# while loop if statements

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I've almost got this thing working, I just can't manage to get the:

`if((pscore <= card1 +card2))` statement to loop until the player either sticks or busts.

from what I can see, it should work... but I'm missing a detail, and I can't figure out what.

```
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Blackjack
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    String name;
    Scanner scannerIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean yourTurn = true;
        boolean dealersTurn =true;
        int card1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int dcard1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int dcard2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);

        int pscore = card1 +card2;
        int dscore = dcard1 +dcard2;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack ! " );
        System.out.println("\nScore as close to 21 without going over to win ");
        System.out.println("\nWhat is your name?");
            name = scannerIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nHello " + name);
        System.out.println("\nLet's play some BlackJack!");
            System.out.println("\nThe dealer shows:\t" +dcard1 );
        System.out.println("\n\nYour first card is:\t " +card1 );
        System.out.println("\nYour second card is:\t" +card2  );
            System.out.println("\nGiving you a grand total of: " +pscore );


    while (yourTurn)
    {
                if ((pscore <= +card1 +card2))
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to (H)it or (S)tick?");
                    String a = scannerIn.nextLine();
                if(a.toLowerCase().equals("h"))
        {
                int newCard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
                System.out.println("\nYour next card is " +newCard );
                    pscore = pscore +newCard;
                System.out.println("\nGiving you a new total of "+pscore);

                if ((pscore >=22))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYou Busted! \nSorry! you lose");
                yourTurn = false;break;
            }
        }

        else if(a.toLowerCase().equals("s"))
        {   
            yourTurn = false;
            System.out.println("\nYou stick at " +pscore );
            System.out.println("\nNow it's the dealers turn\n Dealer must draw until 17");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease press H or S");
        }



    while (dealersTurn)
    {
        dealersTurn = true;
        {   if ((dscore <= dcard1+dcard2))
            System.out.println("\nThe dealers cards were:\n " +dcard1);
            System.out.println("\nand\n" +dcard2);
            System.out.println("\nGiving the Dealer a grand total of: " +dscore );
        }

        {
            int newCard1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
            if ((dscore<=17))
                System.out.println("\nThe dealer draws a: " +newCard1 );
            dscore = dscore +newCard1;
                System.out.println("\nGiving the dealer a grand total of: "+dscore);
        }
            if ((dscore >=22))
        {
            System.out.println("\nDealer Bust!");
            System.out.println("\nThe House loses");
            System.out.println("\nYou Win");
            dealersTurn = false;break;
        }
            else if ((dscore >=pscore))
        {
            System.out.println("\nDealer has " +dscore);
            System.out.println("\nThe dealer beat you!");
            System.out.println("\nThe House Wins!");
            dealersTurn = false;break;
        }
    }
    }
    scannerIn.close();
    }
    }
```

Also, I have a bunch of people to thank, helping me get this far. If there is a +1 button for people I can't find it.

Thanks for the help
Vincent.

Comment: There are more than one errors in your code, maybe you should try to debug first.

Answer (score 0):

Your while(yourTurn) loop does not close its bracket until after the while(dealerTurn) loop. This is causing the dealers turn to be a part of the yourTurn loop. Add a closing bracket above the dealersTurn while loop as follows:

```
 }
 while (dealersTurn)
 {
```

Then remove the old closing bracket from the bottom above "scannerIn.close()"

But also, what is the purpose of your logic

```
 if ((pscore <= +card1 +card2))
```

Your score is = to card1 + card2 and then if you draw another card your score will be greater than those 2 cards since you have 3 cards now. That is why it is also not entering your if statement.